# R QUANTMOD LiteCoin

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to use QuantMod to import some data on LiteCoin #cryptocurrency, can that be used for things other than stocks ?

If so what source would I use ?  example of code below, thanks!

If Quantmod doesn't support it, what is a good data source to use for importation into R ?

```
# Get quantmod
if (!require("quantmod")) {
  install.packages("quantmod")
  library(quantmod)
}

start <- as.Date("2016-11-18")
end <- as.Date("2017-11-18")

getSymbols("LTC.X", src = "???", from = start, to = end)
```

Comment: I think you can only get a few crypto currency from quantmod, it is my understanding the data comes from Yahoo Finance, so if it is not on Yahoo Finance then you will not get it from the quantmod package.  Here is a good article from r-bloggers website: https://www.r-bloggers.com/investigating-cryptocurrencies-part-ii/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ticker "LTC-USD" in yahoo to retrieve LiteCoin data:

```
library(quantmod)
start <- as.Date("2016-11-18")
end <- as.Date("2017-12-15")
ltcData <- getSymbols("LTC-USD", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end, auto.assign = FALSE)
candleChart(ltcData, col=TRUE, theme=chartTheme('white'), log.scale=TRUE, name="LTC" )
```

[image]

Comment: > ltcData <- getSymbols("LTC-USD", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end, auto.assign = FALSE)
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot download all files
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=LTC-USD&a=10&b=18&c=2016&d=11&e=15&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=LTC-USD&x=.csv': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'

Comment: it would be great, if this package expanded to use other sources and not just crappy Yahoo that no one cares about anymore :-)  just my opinion..

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your error message; using quantmod v0.4.12, R v3.4.3 I do obtain the LTC data with the code posted above. My impression is that the issue with the quotes is always kind of difficult. AFAIK, the package can handle any data that can be converted into an xts object. For instance, one can combine `quantmod` with [`Quandl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Quandl/index.html) for data on a few commodities. But one of the main difficulties in general is to get access to the required financial data. I guess that's why many traders rely on commercial sources.